# chefspec test for non core resource

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

Could anyone advise how I can write a chefspec test for the following recipe code please?

```
  {'tomcat_exec_t' => '/apps/.*/bin(/.*)?',
  'tomcat_unit_file_t' => '/usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat@.*.service',
  'tomcat_cache_t' => '/apps/.*/temp(/.*)?',
  'tomcat_cache_t' => '/apps/.*/work(/.*)?',
  'etc_t' => '/apps/.*/conf(/.*)?',
  'tomcat_log_t' => '/apps/.*/logs(/.*)?',
  'tomcat_var_run_t' => '/apps/.*/logs/tomcat.pid',
  'lib_t' => '/apps/.*/lib(/.*)?',
  'tomcat_var_lib_t' => '/apps/.*/webapps(/.*)?'}.each do |sc, f|
    selinux_policy_fcontext f do
      secontext sc
    end
  end
```

I've tried a couple of things like below but I guess this fails because the execute is carried out by the selinux_policy cookbook.

```
expect(chef_run).to run_execute('selinux-fcontext-tomcat_exec_t-addormodify')
  end
```

and this fails because there is no method defined:

```
expect(chef_run).to create_selinux-fcontext('selinux-fcontext-tomcat_exec_t-addormodify').with(
      fspec: '/apps/.*/bin(/.*)?',
      secontext: 'fcontext'
    )
```

So I'm not really sure what else can be done.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Edward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to write your own `matchers` depending on whether or not the selinux cookbook provides them for you.  Check in the libraries directory.

In either case, you would want

```
expect(chef_run).to create_selinux_policy_fcontext('selinux-fcontext-tomcat_exec_t-addormodify').with(
  fspec: '/apps/.*/bin(/.*)?',
  secontext: 'fcontext'
end
```

*I'm assuming that the default action is `create`, otherwise you'd replace `create` with the appropriate action*

Comment: Thanks Tejay, I literally just realised :) https://github.com/BackSlasher/chef-selinuxpolicy/blob/master/libraries/matchers.rb